# How to animate in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

1. > I need to animate in angular-Js. I googled it.    but i can not get
   >       a perfect way to achieve this.
   >
   > ```
   >      html
   >
   >            <span class="sb-arrow down" ng-click="hideSampleList($event)"></span>
   >
   >         js:
   >             $scope.hideSampleList = function ($event) {
   >                 if ($($event.currentTarget).hasClass("down")) {
   >                     $($event.currentTarget).next().hide(300);
   >                 }
   >                 else {
   >                     $($event.currentTarget).removeClass("up");
   >                     $($event.currentTarget).addClass("down");
   >                 }
   >             }
   >
   >
   >         I have used jquery animate.
   >
   >         Here how can i animate(show and hide) in angular js.
   >
   >         can anyone please guide me
   > ```

Comment: Downvote because it's a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249669/how-to-animate-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <span class="sb-arrow down" ng-click="showMyList=true" ng-hide="showMyList"></span>
 <span class="sb-arrow down" ng-click="showMyList=false" ng-show="showMyList"></span>


<div class="sample-list animate-if" ng-if="showMyList">
......
</div>

<style>
/* Angular animate classes */
.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.2s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.2s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.2s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.2s;
}
.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}

/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
</style>
```